# How to adjust row height in excel using openpyxl

Tags: excel, row, height, cell, openpyxl

I'm trying to update text content of a cell by adding multiple lines, but when I save the file the row height is not adjusted and the full content is not visible. Is there any way to get the cell height and put it in `ws.row_dimensions[i].height = cell_height`

Comment: No. The best you can do is work out the approximate height based on the font used in the cell.

Comment: Can I get the rows count in the cell itself?